# comparing the resulting "blocks" object with a list

Tags: javascript

**Hi!**

I've read literally all the articles about using map, filter, and includes in JS, but I still can't figure out how to get the "block"I need from the checks I received and passed.

Task: Inside object A, there are arrays that have the "block" field. This field should be compared with array B and the resulting values saved or simply returned.

First I got the unique values and combined them, and then I started searching in the resulting list, comparing them.

```
a = [ 
  {
    "id":1,
    "title":"123", 
    "url":"123", 
    "password":"123", 
    "totp":"none", 
    "block":"none", 
    "created_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:21.000Z", 
    "updated_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:21.000Z" 
  },
  {
    "id":2, 
    "title":"qwe",
    "url":"qwe",
    "password":"qwe",
    "totp":"none",
    "block":"none",
    "created_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:39.000Z",
    "updated_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:39.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "title":"asd",
    "url":"asd",
    "password":"asd",
    "totp":"none",
    "block":"nne",
    "created_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:42.000Z",
    "updated_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:42.000Z"
  }
];
     
b = ['none', '5235', '5235']
    
    
console.log(
  Array.from(a, 
    ({block}) => block
  )
  .map(
    i => i
  )
  .map(
    al => b.filter(
      bal => bal === al
    )
  )
)
```

Output: [image]

But I would like to see instead of the matched words - the specific objects to which these words belong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `a.filter(({block}) => b.includes(block))`

```js
const a = [
  {"id":1,"title":"123","url":"123","password":"123","totp":"none","block":"none","created_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:21.000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:21.000Z"},
  {"id":2,"title":"qwe","url":"qwe","password":"qwe","totp":"none","block":"none","created_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:39.000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:39.000Z"},
  {"id":3,"title":"asd","url":"asd","password":"asd","totp":"none","block":"nne","created_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:42.000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:42.000Z"}
  ];
 const b = ['none', '5235', '5235']
 
 
const filtered = a.filter(({block}) => b.includes(block));

console.log(filtered);
```